# Laravel Pivot Table - How to increment third field with counter?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, pivot

Hi guys wondering if you can help figure out what this eloquent statement should look like. It's pretty challenging, at least for me, but maybe not for some of you guys? Here is the scenario:

I have a pivot table with post_id and `user_id` and an additional column called `total_views` in the pivot table.

Basically what I'm trying to do is increment the views each time the user goes and view that specific post.

This is what the SQL would look like:

```
UPDATE post_user SET total_views = total_views+1 WHERE user_id=1 AND post_id=2
```

How would you write this in an eloquent statement? Big thanks for the first that can come up with a solution!

Comment: is that necessary to do that via eloquent? raw sql?

Comment: I could do it with sql now, but that would defeat the whole idea of using laravel eloquent if a solution is possible (and I'm sure there is) using eloquent.

Comment: yes, it is possible.

Comment: Ok I got this working: \DB::table('post_user')->increment('total_views')->where(['user_id'=>$user->id, 'post_id'=>$post->id]);

Comment: But now even tho it's incrementing I get a error FatalThrowableError in CompletionsController.php line 63:
Call to a member function where() on integer. Anyone have any ideas why or how to stop it from throwing the error?

Comment: where clauses need to be added before increment function

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo Yep your right, I had put it before the where to try and address something else, moved it to the end, 200 messsage comes back, looks good, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 \DB::table('post_user')->where(['u‌​ser_id'=>$user->id, 'post_id'=>$post->id])->increment('total_views');
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

`DB::table('post_user')->increment('total_views');` and add some where clauses that's with **query builder**.

In **eloquent**, fetch the object, update the values and save.

```
$object = ModelName::find(1); ///use where clauses to get the record
$object->your_preferredColumn = $VALUE; //increment it here
$object->save(); //save the object
```